# Google play developer distribution agreement has changed

Tags: android, google-play

My Google play account is saying

> The Google Play Developer Distribution Agreement changed recently and
>   the account owner has not agreed to the new agreement. Access to this
>   developer console will be blocked until the account owner agrees to
>   the new agreement.

I am not getting any agreement. Please help me, how can I active my Google play account. I am new in Google play, I don't have any idea about this problem.

Comment: If you are the Account owner, you can see the agreement. If you are not the developers account owner, and your access to developers console is created by some other person, you cannot have full rights.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: @Akhil actually my google play account is created by another person  , and i am not getting any agreement.

Comment: That's it. The one who created your access to developes console should deal with it.

Comment: @Akhil please provide me link then i am send link to account created person for verify Please

Comment: @RenuSingh, there is no need of a particular link. Just tell that account owner to login into developers console with his details, he can see the agreement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Distribution link: https://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html

You need to go to https://play.google.com/apps/publish/ and accept the Google Play Developer Distribution Agreement with the primary account. That is the Google account that was used to set up the developer account.

Comment: How can I find who is the 'primary account'?, I've created the apps and I'm not aware of any other accounts to my project...

Comment: @user1406269, did you figure it out? Having the same issue.

Comment: I found the account but I didn't find a way to see who is the primary account.